# How referencing instance method 'encode' on 'Array' can conform to 'Encodable'

Tags: json, swift, core-data

I am having CoreData entity which name is "Lekarstvo". The structure of this entity is the same as the structure of the JSON. I want to transfer this information to the JSON file. How can I do it? Right now I am having this error and I really don't know how to fix it.

> Referencing instance method 'encode' on 'Array' requires that 'Lekarstvo' conform to 'Encodable'

```
func getAllData() {

     var userArr :[Lekarstvo] = []

      do{
               userArr =  try moc.fetch(Lekarstvo.fetchRequest())

      }catch{
              print(error)
      }

        guard let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(userArr) else {return}
            if let jsonString = String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8) {
                print(jsonString)
            }

            guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/vw7sg") else {return}
                        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

                            request.httpMethod = "PUT"
                            request.httpBody = encoded
```

[image]

Comment: The solution is here: _"Referencing instance method 'encode' on 'Array' requires that 'Lekarstvo' conform to 'Encodable'"_. That is you need to make your class conform to the protocol.

Comment: Can you please help me with that?

Comment: [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your struct/class conforms to Codable (or Encodable) + all it's subfields need to conform to the same protocol.

```
struct Lekarstvo: Codable {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by adding this for loop and it works now.

```
  for data in userArr as! [NSManagedObject] {
        let dossi = LecarstvO(id: data.value(forKey: "id") as! Int,
                              kgPazient: data.value(forKey: "kgPazient") as! Int,
                              goPazient: data.value(forKey: "goPazient") as! Int,
                              fromMin: data.value(forKey: "fromMin") as! CGFloat,
                              toMin: data.value(forKey: "toMin") as! CGFloat,
                              fromMax: data.value(forKey: "fromMax") as! CGFloat,
                              toMax: data.value(forKey: "toMax") as! CGFloat,
                              isMin: data.value(forKey: "isMin") as! Bool,
                              isMax: data.value(forKey: "isMax") as! Bool,
                              mjarka: data.value(forKey: "mjarka") as! String,
                              maxDoza: data.value(forKey: "maxDoza") as! CGFloat,
                              firstDoza: data.value(forKey: "firstDoza") as! CGFloat,
                              priemI: data.value(forKey: "priemI") as! Int,
                              priemII: data.value(forKey: "priemII") as! Int,
                              opis: data.value(forKey: "opis") as! String,
                              lekarstvo: data.value(forKey: "lekarstvo") as! String,
                              grupa: data.value(forKey: "grupa") as! String)
                     self.model.database.append(dossi)
    }
```

Comment: What has this got to do with json encoding?

Answer (score 1):

for data in userArr as! [NSManagedObject]